# How compiler allows user defined operator new

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

Header file < new > defines operator new and similar versions. It also mentions these functions are inserted into each translation file.

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size);
```

Standard allows overloading of these functions. For overloading to be successful there should be some difference in the signature. My doubt is how standard or compiler allows user to overload operator new with same signature.
Below is my global overload of operator new.

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size) {
    std::cout << "My operator new size: " << size << std::endl;
    return malloc(size);
}
```

Comment: The standard does not allow overloading of operator new. It allows **replacing**it. Usually that means linker magic, and it just works. But be very careful what you do inside your replacement version. Stream insertion sometimes requires allocating an internal buffer, and that will use operator new, and you’ll get deep recursion and a crash. In this situation, use `printf`; it won’t call any C++ stuff.

Comment: @PeteBecker do you have any reference document for this linker magic?

Comment: Nope, no specific documentation. Generally, if a name has already been resolved, seeing a duplicate in a subsequent library is harmless, unless there's another name in the same object file from the library that forces the duplicate to be pulled in as well. This is fairly deep implementation details; when you add Windows DLLs into the equation things can get nasty. It's up to the implementor to get it right.